# What does "requires ipykernel package" mean and how to fix?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, google-colaboratory, vscode-extensions

```
Running cells with 'Python 3.8.1 64-bit' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment. 
Command: '"c:/Users/Yash Pakhale/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe" -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'
```

Comment: Did something go wrong when you did what the message told you to do?

Comment: no just did what it said ,and ran the code again but getting same error